# Default value of option not coming in angular in IE only

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown where the values are getting iterated from some API:

```
 <select
              class="form-control"
              #motCriteriaVal
              [(ngModel)]="firstKey_motCriteriaVal1"
              name="motCriteria"
            >
              <option
                *ngFor="let motCritValue of ObjectKeys(motCriteriaVal1)"
                >{{ motCriteriaVal1[motCritValue] }}</option
              >
            </select>
```

`motCriteriaVal1` is like this:

```
 { "key1": "key1Val", "key2": "key2Val", "key3": "key3Val" }
```

So requirement is that I should see the options as 'key1Val'and sso on, but when i click on a button, the value executed to an API call should be the key (key1 and so on). That is why i used `ObjectKeys` and its working fine in in Firefox and chrome. But in IE (i am testing in IE11) the default value is not showing on page load.

So i tired this:

```
 <option [value]="firstKey_motCriteriaVal1"
                *ngFor="let motCritValue of ObjectKeys(motCriteriaVal1)"
                >{{ motCriteriaVal1[motCritValue] }}</option
              >
```

It is showing me the default value in IE11 also, but, when i click on a button where the values in select are to be sent to an API, the same dafault value is sent, if I change the option in drop-down

Please help.

Comment: why are you using firstKey_motCriteriaVal1 property to set value option?

Comment: to set default value

Comment: Inside option value you have to pass looped data